# autocompleting a word that contains a colon

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I am making a autocompletion function for a program `foo` that has some subcommands like:

```
foo lists:show
foo list:create <list_name>
```

So far I have something working:

```
# file: foo_completion.sh
_foo_completion_func ()
{
    local cur
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    case "$cur" in
        t*) COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'list:show' -- $cur ) );;
    esac
    return 0
}
complete -F _foo_completion_func -o filenames foo
```

So If I do `source foo_completion.sh` 
and then `foo li`<kbd>Tab</kbd> I get it autocompleted but the output is :

```
foo list\:show
```

With a `\` prior the colon. It works, apparently it is just a visual thing but I wish there I get `foo list:show` instead of `foo list\:show`. Is this possible? Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The colon is escaped as part of filename processing. Try dropping the `-o filenames`. If you still need that, I'm not sure if there is a way to selectively disable it.